# Изменение jmp в IDA

Tags: ассемблер

Изучаю IDA и в процессе ознакомления столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Есть код, который проверяет пароль на правильность:

```
if (strcmp(console_pass, original_pass) == 0) {
        printf("Welcome!");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("Access denied");
        return 1;
    }
```

По условию, в IDA необходимо изменить команду jmp так, чтобы пароль в любом случае подходил.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как перейти в блок "Welcome!" или же как найти адрес данного блока и вписать его в jmp.

Comment: вы понимаете, что выделенный вами jmp стоит уже после `printf("Welcome!")`?

Comment: Данный адрес ссылается на блок выше

Comment: Чтобы блок с `printf("Welcome!");` всегда выполнялся, нужно просто "удалить" jle - пропатчить его nop-ами.